# CoqIde strange message upon auto tactics

Tags: coq

Upon using the **auto** or **eauto** item from Try Tactics CoqIde responds with the following message no matter where the current position is:

```
Currently, the parsing api only supports parsing at the tip of the document.
You wanted to parse at: 0 but the current tip is: 54
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Coq [maybe already fixed in the `master` branch]. Please, report at https://github.com/coq/coq/issues